# ePOS2 Android SDK com.epson.epos2.linedisplay.LineDisplay.finalize() timed out

Tags: android, timeoutexception, epson

I'm facing a TimeoutException when using the Android Epson ePOS2 SDK (v2.27.0)

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.epson.epos2.linedisplay.LineDisplay.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at com.epson.epos2.linedisplay.LineDisplay.nativeEpos2Disconnect(LineDisplay.java)
       at com.epson.epos2.linedisplay.LineDisplay.finalize(LineDisplay.java:457)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem or can offer insights into why this occurs? Additionally, if anyone has recommendations on how to directly reach out to Epson for support, that information would also be greatly appreciated.